# Write and read a struct in C?

Tags: c, file, struct, io, fread

so at first I create my struct:

> struct interest *p =malloc(256);

And assign variables inside the struct:

```
  p -> num = 1;
  p -> size = 2;
  p -> name = "jacky";
```

After I opend my output file, I write this struct to it:

```
 fwrite(&p,sizeof(p), 1, output_file);
```

**Here is my first question, if I want to write a struct p, is putting it as "&p" correct?**

Assume I have successfully written it, and I wanna know read the struct from my output_file.
I then proceed to:

```
...#open the outputfile for reading
```

> struct interest *buff = malloc(256);
>
> fread(&buff, sizeof(buff),1,output_file);

I then get a segamentation fault when I try to print buff's num or size..

**What
is the correct way of doing it?**

The reason why I want to print it is because I wanna check if I have really written that struct into the output file.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a minimal program that reproduces your error, and not just a few lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

Error 1)

You cant do:

```
p -> name = "jacky"
```

Use:

```
strcpy(p->name, "jacky");
```

instead.

Error 2)

Struct has a fixed lenght and you are allocating 256 byte to it? Perhaps what you wanted is:

```
 struct interest *p =malloc(sizeof(struct interest));
```

Error 3)

Use:

```
fwrite(p,sizeof(struct interest), 1, output_file);
```

p is already a pointer

Post your struct declaration. You could have more problems on it.

Comment: Thanks! what if name is a pointer itself? And I want make name point to "jacky"?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make

```
p = malloc(sizeof(struct interest))
```

Second, `p` and `buff` are already pointers, you should write:

```
fwite(p, sizeof(struct interest), fp)
fread(buff, sizeof(struct interest), fp)
```

Finnally, to copy string, you should write

```
<string.h>
strncpy(p->name, "jacky", sizeof(p->name))
```

Comment: Thanks! For the first one, should I declare p as "struct packet *p;" first? Also, what if name is a pointer itself? And I want make name point to "jacky"?